# How to set css module in webpack.config file?

Tags: reactjs

{
test: cssRegex,
exclude: cssModuleRegex,
use: getStyleLoaders({
importLoaders: 1,
modules:{
localIdentName: '[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]'
},
sourceMap: isEnvProduction
? shouldUseSourceMap
: isEnvDevelopment,
}),
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        modules: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see in the config, you need to use two loaders, style-loader and css-loader. You also need to install them as NPM dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader
```

`modules: true` that tells css-loader to enable CSS modules.

`importLoaders: 1` means that it also applies CSS modules on @imported resources.